# Why does my softmax plot not look like a max plot?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, softmax

Why "softmax" is called "softmax"? How is it related to "max"?

I am trying  the following code and the results do not look like each other:

```r
a = seq(-1,1,0.05)
b = seq(-1,1,0.05)

softmax <- function(x,y) {
  exp(y)/(exp(x)+exp(y))
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

c = outer(a,b,pmax)
persp(a,b,c)

d = outer(a,b,softmax)
persp(a,b,d)
```

[image]

The two plots are not similar at all.

Comment: Possible related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/298849/26948

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/Why-is-softmax-activate-function-called-softmax and https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-term-soft-max-mean-in-the-context-of-machine-learning and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888141/why-is-the-softmax-function-called-that-way

Comment: This should be reopened - it is not a duplicate of the linked question (that is about understanding a smooth approximation of the _max_ function, not the _argmax_ function as softmax is).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function#Smooth_arg_max answers this question.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed on the [Mathematics Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888141/why-is-the-softmax-function-called-that-way), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-softmax-activate-function-called-softmax), and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function#Smooth_arg_max), softmax is a "soft" version of argmax, rather than maximum. So instead of using `max`, you should rather call something like `which.max` (in R) or `argmax` (in Python/Numpy or Julia) that return the *position* of the largest value, not the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggested, Softmax is a soft version of argmax. Therefore, it will return a vector instead of a scalar.

The additional step, $\text{sofmax}(x)^T x$ make the the final scalar output.

The make the plot similar and see the "soft" surface plot. The code should be

```
a = seq(-5,5,0.1)
b = seq(-5,5,0.1)

df = expand.grid(a,b)
df$m = apply(df,1,max)
df$sm = apply(df,1,softmax)

softmax <- function(x) {
  p = c(exp(x[1])/(exp(x[1])+exp(x[2])),exp(x[2])/(exp(x[1])+exp(x[2]))) 
  q = c(x[1],x[2])
  p %*% q
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

c = matrix(df$m,ncol=sqrt(nrow(df)))
persp(a,b,c)

d = matrix(df$sm,ncol=sqrt(nrow(df)))
persp(a,b,d)
```

[image]